# How to smooth DC output from an op-amp precision full wave rectifier?

Tags: single-supply-op-amp, precision-rectifier

I am using the circuit below to rectify the AC voltage from a current sensing transformer. It is a single supply full wave rectifier, which I intend to use to measure this voltage with a microcontroller. I would like to simply smooth the output voltage into a DC output matching the peak of the sine wave input. In a traditional FBR circuit this is done with a capacitor, but I do not know how to do it on an op-amp rectifier circuit. Does anyone have any suggestions.

[image: Single supply full-wave rectifier circuit.]

[image: Simulation results]

Answer (score 1):

Same way, just use an RC filter on the output. If you need something more precise then use a [sallen key butterworth opamp filter](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiLowkeisan.htm). You'll get a filtered value so if you need to do peak detection to find the max value, then you'll need a peak detection circuit

Comment: Your simple rectifier is half-wave, not full-wave. it will take fairly high value capacitors in the filter and peak detector to filter away the 30Hz.